# How to access return label pdf via API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, shippo

When I create an instance of `Shippo::Transaction`, I get access to transaction pdf from `label_url` field.  How can I get access to pdf for return label?

I tried to create an instance of `Shippo::Shipment` with `address_return` or/and `return_of` fields and I received any link to my return label pdf from API response.  I can do it only using web version.

I haven't found anything about this issue in API documentation.

Comment: add some additional useful tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Shippo return label docs](https://goshippo.com/docs/return-labels#return-label).

The process of creating a return label is the same as the outbound label, just with the addition of the `return_of` field in the Shipment.

1. Create a `Shippo::Shipment` with `return_of` set to the `object_id` of the outbound Transaction object.
2. Purchase one of the returned rates by creating a `Shippo::Transaction`.

(Altrnatively you can also purchase return labels in one API call with the [Shippo Single Label Call Creation](https://goshippo.com/docs/single-call).)

Comment: for some reason this both solution doesn't work for me.
When I try to create return label in one API call with this params

`foo = Shippo::Transaction.create(shipment: "04246b7be7004ae5a60a5c9e32aca124", carrier_account: "ce24d26c1bba45ddb7204e212e517708", servicelevel_token: "usps_priority")`

I get 

`Shippo::APIError: error: 500 Internal Server Error <h1>Server Error (500)</h1>`

Comment: and when I'm trying to do it via new shipment
`new_shipment = Shippo::Shipment.create(return_of: "921fd04dfff547b3ae5d955da67ccc69", address_to: previous_shipment[:address_from], address_from: previous_shipment[:address_to], parcel: previous_shipment[:parcel])` and then new transaction `new_transaction = Shippo::Transaction.create(rate: new_shipment.rates.first[:object_id], async: false)`  I get transaction JSON object from API with error message `The given Rate can't be purchased because it's object_purpose is not PURCHASE.`

Comment: @MykhailoBohoslavskyi would you mind posting your full API request or your Shippo username? Or feel free to just send it to support@goshippo.com. This allows us to look into the details and we can debug it much faster :)